# How do I search a txt file for names from command line or interactive command line

Tags: bash, gedit

I am trying to make a script that will either take command line input after or if user input is null then an interactive prompt will as for a name to be used to search a text file. I'm using bash  and gedit.

I want it to go like this:

> ./scriptName input

if inupt is null

echo Please enter a name.

I'm just getting started and I cannot figure out how to get this first part to function.

Comment: The usual behavior for Unix tools is to read standard input if called without a file name. Maybe you don't want to deviate from this convention?

Comment: I'm just attempting to recreate something show from a classso I can better understand the lesson. Thank you for the tip though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

name="$1"
if [[ "$name" == "" ]]; then
  read -p "Please enter a name:" name
fi

# continue
```

Comment: Yea that looks like it will get me started! Thank you!